# How can I add a beep to ZSH's prompt?

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh

I want to be notified when a job is done or something finishes in a terminal, and I read somewhere about adding a Bell to the command prompt, and then turning on urgentOnBell. But I can't figure out how to add the bell properly to my ZSH prompt. Everything just prints \a. [\a] doesn't work, %{\a%} doesn't work, \a doesn't work. What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. I added:

```
%{$(echo "\a")%}
```

Maybe not the prettiest (there's gotta be a way simply to output an escape code correctly) but it works.

Comment: `PS1+=$'%{\a%}'` seems to be working.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem a while ago and found a working solution although it does not quite make a beep.

```
sudo apt-get install espeak
espeak "job complete"
```

Comment: I laugh in front of my computer every time I hear `espeak "BEEP"`, for example when I need a timer : `sleep 60 && espeak "BEEP"`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `OSX`, you can use the built-in `Say` command:

```bsh
Say  "job complete"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use Morse code. If you can understand that code, you can also distinguish between multiple jobs, terminals, etc.

```
sudo apt-get install morse
your-command && morse "e"
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code

Answer (score 0):

You can add the literal control character to the prompt line. In `vim`, in insert mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> will output the bell character. It'll then be displayed as, e.g., `^G$_USERNAME $_PATH`

However, I've found that adding it to the prompt will cause the terminal to bell again upon e.g. resize. Adding it to a precmd-hook seems to be the better solution, e.g.

```
precmd_bell () {
    print "^G"
}

add-zsh-hook precmd precmd_bell
```